# Mathdesign changes \mu-sign in siunitx when used with lualatex, but not with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, luatex, mathdesign

I recently encountered an issue with the `\mu`-sign in siunitx while working on my thesis. Compiling the following code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
    Hello World
    
    \SI{100}{\micro\meter}=\SI{100000}{\nano\meter}
    
    $1\mu=1000$
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex` gives

[image]

but when compiling the same code with `lualatex` I get

[image]

If I remove `mathdesign` I do not have those issues. What is mathdesign doing to change `\mu` to a `ƫ`, and how can I fix it?

Comment: mathdesign switches to T1 encoding and so is not suitable for lualatex.

Comment: Is there an alternative to mathdesign I can use, or force mathdesign to switch to T1? I'm trying to adapt a given template from pdflatex to lualatex.

Comment: well depends why you use mathdesign. Basically you should setup the fonts with fontspec and unicode-math in lualatex.

Comment: A quick-and-likely-dirty fix would to revert to version 2 of `siunitx` by executing `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]`.

Comment: @Mico no, that would cure only one symptom. But the document would still use T1 encoding and you would get problems in other places. Better would be to load fontspec after mathdesign, but the best is to really analyse which fonts are wanted and to setup them correctly.