# Changed math fonts in lualatex compared to pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex, newtxmath, xcharter

I am trying to update a thesis template I got to work non only with `pdflatex`, but also with `lualatex` (to enable larger tikz-figures, mostly). Following the received comments to [Mathdesign changes \mu-sign in siunitx when used with lualatex, but not with pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/628878/61517) I wrote the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openright]{book}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}                     % selecting text color
\usepackage{pdfpages}                   % including pdf files

%% PACKAGE LOADING
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
\DeclareSymbolFont{charteraccents}{T1}{XCharter-TLF}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{charteraccents}{bold}{T1}{XCharter-TLF}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\grave}{\mathalpha}{charteraccents}{0}
\DeclareMathAccent{\acute}{\mathalpha}{charteraccents}{1}
\DeclareMathAccent{\hat}{\mathalpha}{charteraccents}{2}
\DeclareMathAccent{\tilde}{\mathalpha}{charteraccents}{3}
\DeclareMathAccent{\ddot}{\mathalpha}{charteraccents}{4}
\DeclareMathAccent{\mathring}{\mathalpha}{charteraccents}{6}
\DeclareMathAccent{\check}{\mathalpha}{charteraccents}{7}
\DeclareMathAccent{\breve}{\mathalpha}{charteraccents}{8}
\DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{charteraccents}{9}
\DeclareMathAccent{\dot}{\mathalpha}{charteraccents}{10}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[xcharter]{newtxmath}

\setmainfont{XCharter}[NFSSFamily=XCharter]
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setsansfont[Scale=.88]{DejaVuSans}
\setmonofont[Scale=.82]{DejaVuSansMono}
\setmathrm{XCharter}
\setboldmathrm{XCharter Bold}
\else
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % for special characters in input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % modern font encoding
\usepackage[charter, cal=cmcal]{mathdesign} % main font with math support
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[scaled=.88]{berasans}       % sans serif font
\usepackage[scaled=.82]{DejaVuSansMono} % monospace font (for code)
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % advanced math typesetting
\fi
\usepackage[english]{babel}    % language specifics
\usepackage{siunitx}
 \begin{document}
    Hello World

    $100\text{ coins are 100 coins}$

    \SI{100}{\micro\meter} are 100 \textmu m

    100/\num{100}=1
 \end{document}
```

When compiling with `pdflatex`, I get the following result:
[image]

but when compiling with `lualatex`, I get a slightly different result:
[image]

The math font is obviously slightly off. What can I do to make the result of `lualatex` at least comparable, if not equal, to `pdflatex`? And are there other mistakes?

Comment: Seems that `\mathrm` is defaulting to CMR under lualatex.  Best might be to `\renewcommand\rmdefault{..}` before loading `newtxmath`, however I am unsure of the correct font naming {..} to get you XCharter at that point; perhaps someone else can help.  A few other notes: `ifluatex` should be replaced with the more recent `iftex`; `newtxmath` requires `amsmath`, so you don't need to load it separately; and `newtx` documentation recommends loading `fontspec` _after_ `newtxmath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a number of adjustments to your code (and dropped some lines that weren't relevant to the example).  I've added comments that I hope explain, but very briefly: i) the order in which packages are loaded matters; ii) when using `newtxmath` with `fontspec`, you must load the text fonts that get folded into math before loading `newtxmath`; and iii) fontspec must come after `newtxmath`.  I put the fonts loaded by `fontspec` in color so it would be clear which they are.

There's more that can be done to match the scale of the lualatex fonts to the pdftex packages, but this gives a first approximation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % selecting text color

\usepackage[english]{babel}% <== babel should be loaded before newtx
%\usepackage{ifluatex}% <== obsolete
\usepackage{iftex}% <== use this current version instead

\ifluatex
    %\usepackage{amsmath} <== newtx requires amsmath, need not load separately
    %
    % Load these to provide characters for math, prior to dealing with actual text fonts
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%  math font encoding
    \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{XCharter-TLF}%   font family for \mathrm, numbers, \mathbf, \mathit
    \usepackage[scaled=.88]{berasans}% for \mathsf
    \usepackage[scaled=.82]{DejaVuSansMono} % monospace font for \mathtt
    %
    \usepackage[charter]{newtxmath}
    \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}% load after newtxmath
    % 
    % Added colors so you can see which OTF fonts have loaded
    \setmainfont{XCharter}[
        NFSSFamily=XCharter,
        Color=teal,
        Extension = .otf,
        UprightFont = *-Roman,
        ItalicFont = *-Italic,
        BoldFont = *-Bold,
        BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,%
    ]       
    %\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}% <== this is the default setting of fontspec    
    \setsansfont[
        Scale=.88,
        Color=red, 
        Extension = .ttf, 
        UprightFont = *,
        ItalicFont = *-Oblique,
        BoldFont = *-Bold,
        BoldItalicFont = *-BoldOblique,%
        WordSpace = {0.75},% appears that word spacing is lower in the pdftex packages, but more adjustments could be done.
        ]{DejaVuSans}%
    \setmonofont[
        Scale=.82,% Scale=0.82 seems small, might 0.88 be better?
        Color=blue,
        Extension = .ttf, 
        UprightFont = *,
        ItalicFont = *-Oblique,
        BoldFont = *-Bold,
        BoldItalicFont = *-BoldOblique,%
        WordSpace = {0.75},
        ]{DejaVuSansMono}
\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % for special characters in input
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % modern font encoding
    \usepackage[scaled=.88]{berasans}       % sans serif font <== loading order matters
    \usepackage[scaled=.82]{DejaVuSansMono} % monospace font (for code) <== loading order matters
    \usepackage[charter, cal=cmcal]{mathdesign} % main font with math support
    \usepackage{XCharter}
    \usepackage{amsmath}                    % advanced math typesetting
\fi
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    Hello World. \textsf{Hello World.} \texttt{Hello World.}

    \textit{Hello World. \textsf{Hello World.} \texttt{Hello World.}}
    
    \textbf{Hello World. \textsf{Hello World.} \texttt{Hello World.}}
    
    \textbf{\textit{Hello World. \textsf{Hello World.} \texttt{Hello World.}}}

    $100\text{ coins are 100 coins}$  
    
    \SI{100}{\micro\meter} are 100 \textmu m

    100/\num{100}=1
    
    \[f(x) = A \sin x\cos x\, \]
    
    $\mathrm{100~m}\quad \mathbf{100~m}\quad \mathsf{100~m}\quad \mathtt{100~m}$
     
 \end{document}
```

Under pdflatex:
[image: pdflatex version]
Under lualatex:
[image: luatex version]

Comment: Thanks! Something I'm curious about: Why are you loading `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` not only for `pdflatex`, but also for `lualatex`? As far as I know (following f.ex. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412757/61517) it is not required at all. Or is it just to provide fonts, which then are changed to TU later?

Comment: It's loaded to support the math fonts when `LuaLaTeX` is used. These fonts are chosen from the current text fonts; and since math is loaded before `fontspec`, we need to specify the text fonts that are used and their encoding; otherwise we default to computer modern fonts or TU encodings. In particular, `fontenc` is needed for the sans and tt font packages, so that T1 encoded fonts are sought instead of TU  versions of those fonts (which aren't available, try commenting out `fontenc` and look at the result). The text fonts loaded by `fontspec` are in the default TU (unicode) encoding.